# Adjacent inline-block elements are displaced upon adding text. (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, mootools, css

I'm having an annoying problem which I believe is completely explained by the title of this question and this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X3ebs/2/)

```
#body {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}
#container {
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #000;
}
.innerContainer {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 9.5%;
    background-color: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text {
    height : 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
}
#button {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your `.innerContainer` is set to `display: inline-block;` you need to add `vertical-align: top;` inorder to set the element right.

```
.innerContainer {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 9.5%;
    background-color: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X3ebs/4/)

Comment: Perfect Alien, thanks. It works--but I don't understand why the initial code didn't work. Could you explain why the vertical-align property is needed please?

Comment: @SexyBachelor inline elements sit on the baseline, so I used `top` to shift it up, you can read [this](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/), not completely relevant to the issue but it will give you an idea :) and you welcome

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the link. It's curious that the outer element gets aligned using the inner element's text, but I guess that's very useful in some cases. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
.innerContainer {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 9.5%;
background-color: #F00;
display: inline-block; /* float:left; */
}
```